Prove this limit problem wrong
$ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.

The path $ABC$ is twice as long as $AC$.  Similarly the path $ADEFC$ is
also twice as long as $AC$, as is the path $AGHIEJKLC$, and so on. Breaking down the jagged path into smaller and smaller jags, the
deviation of the jaged path from the straight line $AC$ goes to zero,
so, in a sense, the line $AC$ is the "limit" of the sequence of
jagged paths.  This seems to suggest that the length of $AC$
is twice the length of itself!

This is obviously wrong, but why$?$

Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/188d12g/so_whats_the_actual_explanation_of_why_proof_that/?rdt=46200

"In a sense" it's the limit.  But it's not the right sense.

The answer is simply that this notion of length is not preserved under this notion of limit. There is no reason to expect this to be true.

The curve approximating the line is not differential/smooth. This leads to some fractal effects that can cause things like this to happen. It's like the proof that $pi$ is 4: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4

Let us add Cartesian coordinates so that $A=(0,0),$ $B=(\frac12, \frac12\sqrt{3}),$ and $C=(1,0).$
The length of the graph of a smooth function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is given by
$$
L[f] = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx.
$$
We have a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $f_1$ having $ABC$ as graph, $f_2$ having $ADEFC$ as graph, and so on. We notice that for all $n$ we have
$$
L[f_n] = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+f_n'(x)^2}\,dx = 2.
$$
But we also have pointwise convergence $f_n(x)\to z(x) := 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ as $n\to\infty$ and
$$
L[z] = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+z'(x)^2}\,dx = 1.
$$
The paradox then is that $L[f_n] \not\to L[z]$ although $f_n \to z.$
The solution to the paradox is that although $f_n\to z$ we do not have $f_n' \to z'.$ Therefore the integral for $L[f_n]$ does not converge to the integral for $L[z].$

This is the sort of the answer I was thinking of writing, but I don't quite agree with your logic. What you write is about the failure of a sufficient condition for convergence of length: that theorem (convergence of derivatives implies convergence of length) doesn't apply, and so one would not expect convergence. But it does not imply failure of convergence.

Are the vertices not a problem for the differentiability of $f_n$?

@LeeMosher. We have $|f_n'|=\sqrt3$ so $L[f_n] = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(\sqrt 3)^2},dx.$ How could this possibly converge to $L[z] = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+0^2},dx$?

@DavideMasi. Yes, the vertices are a problem. The correct statement should be that if $f$ is piecewise smooth, say on the intervals $[a_0:=0,a_1), (a_1, a_2), \ldots, (a_{n-1}, a_n:=1],$ then the length of the graph is given by $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{a_k}^{a_{k+1}} \sqrt{1+f'(x)},dx.$$ This can be written as $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2},dx$ where we just exclude the problematic points.

@mt2perpe: To clarify, my remarks were about your final paragraph. Namely, the convergence property $f'_n \to z'$ mentioned in that paragraph is a sufficient condition in general for the convergence property $L[f_n] \to L[z]$, but it is not a necessary condition.

@LeeMosher. I get it. In general it is not even the case that $f_n\to z$ implies $\int F(f_n(x)), dx\to \int F(z(x)), dx,$ less so that $\int F(f_n'(x)),dx\to \int F(z'(x)),dx.$

This is very similar to an argument where $\pi = 4$, where you take a circle of radius $1$ inscribed in a square with side lengths of $2$ and flip inside each of the corners repeatedly until the square approaches the shape of the circle. Of course, $\pi$ isn't $4$. The flaw in this reasoning is that, in terms of length, increasingly small jagged edges under a limit are fundamentally distinct from smooth curves and lines.
The point of a limit is that it should approach the target value over time. However, in this process, the length of the jagged line does not get any closer to $AC$ under any number of iterations since it is constant. Therefore, interpreting the limit as equal to $AC$ is incorrect.
